# Utilização de ferramenta sob GPLv3 "contamina" minha aplicação?

Tags: licença

Estou em um projeto em que utilizarei o SQLite como banco de dados em uma aplicação comercial com direitos reservados.

Até aqui, tudo bem, visto que o SQLite é de domínio público e por esse motivo pode ser alterado sem qualquer restrição e combinado com qualquer outra licença.

Ocorre que a ferramenta que pretendo utilizar é o SQLite Studio que está sob licença GPLv3 e pelo que li até agora trabalhos derivados desta licença devem ter a mesma licença (GPLv3).

Minha interpretação está errada, ou posso utilizar essa ferramenta sem problemas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu trabalho é uma modificação de um software licensiado sob GPLv3?

Se sim, então você está certo. De acordo com [a documentação oficial](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLCommercially):

> **If I use a piece of software that has been obtained under the GNU GPL, am I allowed to modify the original code into a new program, then distribute and sell that new program commercially? (#GPLCommercially)**
>
> You are allowed to sell copies of the modified program commercially, but only under the terms of the GNU GPL. Thus, for instance, you must make the source code available to the users of the program as described in the GPL, and they must be allowed to redistribute and modify it as described in the GPL.
>
> These requirements are the condition for including the GPL-covered code you received in a program of your own.

Em PT-BR:

> **Se eu usar um software que foi obtido sob GNU GPL, eu posso modificar o código original, distribuí-lo e vendê-lo comercialmente?**
>
> Você pode vender comercialmente cópias do programa modificado, mas somente sob os termos da GNU GPL. Portanto você deve disponibilizar o código fonte para os usuários do programa conforme descrito na GPL, e eles devem ser capazes de redistribuí-lo e modificá-lo conforme descrito na GPL.
>
> Esses requisitos são a condição para a inclusão, em um programa seu, de um código protegido pela GPL que você recebeu.

Dos dois softwares que você descreveu, somente o SQLite Studio é coberto pela GPLv3. Se você utilizar o SQLite Studio apenas para desenvolver, mas não for redistribuí-lo, você não precisa seguir ou utilizar a licença GPLv3 nos seus entregáveis.

O SQLite estar sob domínio público não significa que você possa utilizá-lo de graça. Existem algumas restrições de uso, de acordo com [sua página de licenças](https://sqlite.org/copyright.html). Felizmente para você, o uso comercial não é restrito.

Se você entregar seu software com o SQLite "de fábrica" (i.e.: como você o obteve), você não poderá licenciar o SQLite. Outras pessoas e empresas terão o direito irrevogável de criar outros softwares que possam ler e escrever na base de dados que seu software utiliza. Porém, se você modificar o código fonte do SQLite para lhe dar novas funcionalidades, você terá um produto derivado, e aí poderá licenciá-lo também.

Comment: Quanto ao uso do SQLite Studio, agradeço a explicação. Minha intenção é somente utilizá-lo na produção da aplicação. Quanto ao uso do banco de dados SQLite fiquei um pouco confuso se posso licenciar ou não meu software como direitos reservados, pois como exemplo, o Avast utiliza o SQLite e não encontro seu banco disponível para modificações.

Comment: Nada relacionado ao grosso da resposta, mas não vi nada inerente ao SQLite que impeça o uso gratuito. Proteção contra copyright, jurisprudência que não reconhece a licença de domínio público, jurisprudência que não reconhece que o autor pode colocar a obra em domínio público, evidência tangivelmente legal de que pode usar o produto, departamento legal diz para você comprar uma licença (sem maiores explicações). Todos os 5 motivos ao meu ver são externos ao SQLite, portanto ele não limitaria o uso

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado exato, você pode usar comercialmente sem problemas.

Comment: @AnonReports você pode incluir uma obra de domínio público como parte de sua obra, desde que você não tente licenciar a parte de domínio público. I.e.: o fato de a Disney fazer um filme contando uma história dos irmãos Grimm não a torna dona das histórias dos irmãos Grimm - ela é dona apenas do trabalho derivado. É a mesma coisa com Avast e SQLite. Sobre não encontrá-lo para modificações, não sei responder pois não uso Avast.

Comment: Então no meu caso, em uma aba SOBRE posso indicar que meu software tem seus direitos reservados e que utiliza o SQLite como banco de dados e somente este não está licenciado juntamente com meu software?

Comment: @AnonReports creio que sim. Eu tomaria o cuidado de ler mais sobre a licença do SQLite, para ver se ele requer algo mais no "sobre" (i.e.: indicar data e versão), mas no geral é isso.